# How do I set code snippet for woocommerce, paypal and coupons

Tags: php, woocommerce, paypal, code-snippets, coupon

I need to set the possibility to use a coupon to activate a payment method.

For example "PayPal" will only show when a specific coupon is placed.

I need this because i use PayPal with fixed monthly payments without interest.

I have this code to disable paypal if a coupon is used, might be a reverse case, but i couldnt make it work yet.

```html
/*
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bdev_unset_gatway_if_coupon');
function bdev_unset_gatway_if_coupon($available_gateways)
{

    $coupons = WC()->cart->applied_coupons;
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

        if ($coupon) {

            // if the coupon name exist, remove BACS
            unset($available_gateways['paypal']);
        }

    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
*/

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'unset_gatway_by_applied_coupons');

function unset_gatway_by_applied_coupons($available_gateways)
{

    $coupons = WC()->cart->applied_coupons;

    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

        if ($coupon == 'enviodecen') { //here you can specific your coupon name
            unset($available_gateways['paypal']);
        }

    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We could use some more information, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you still looking for the answer to this question? if not, please delete it